# Implementing Multilevel Java Interfaces in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, scala-java-interop

I have following hierarchy in `java` for my `interface`

```
public interface Identifiable<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Serializable {
    public T getId();
}
public interface Function extends Identifiable {
    public String getId();
}
public abstract class Adapter implements Function {
    public abstract String getId();
}
```

When I try to implement `Adapter` in `scala` as follows

```
class MultiGetFunction extends Adapter {
  def getId() : String = this.getClass.getName
}
```

I am getting following error

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - overriding method getId in trait Identifiable of type ()T; method getId has incompatible 
     type
    - overrides Adapter.getId
    - implements Function.getId
    - implements Identifiable.getId
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5279149/1296806 which includes a classic paulp response.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, it is a pain working with raw types in java code from Scala.

Try the below:

```
public interface Function extends Identifiable<String> {
    public String getId();
}
```

The error is probably due to inability of compiler to determine the type `T` as no type is mentioned when declaring `Function extends Identifiable`. This is explained from error:

> :17: error: overriding method getId in trait Identifiable of
>   type ()T;  method getId has incompatible type

Scala is made to be compatible with Java 1.5 and greater. For the previous versions, you need to hack around.
If you cannot change `Adapter`, then you can create a Scala wrapper in Java:

```
public abstract class ScalaAdapter extends Adapter {

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getScalaId();
    }

    public abstract String getScalaId();

}
```

And then use this in Scala:

```
scala>   class Multi extends ScalaAdapter {
     |      def getScalaId():String = "!2"
     |   }
defined class Multi
```

Comment: Thanks Jatin, But I cannot change Java Definition and my Java version is 1.6

Comment: @Avinash Updated the code. This should make it work.